# CSS class can be applied manually, but JavaScript doesn't do it (Really weird problem)

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a navbar at the top of my page, and I am able to apply the hover effect onto all my items on the bar except the one with the icon on it.

When I type the code into the terminal the CSS effect does come in but the hover effect doesn't work. Also, using any CSS pseudo selectors didn't help at all.

```html
<div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarSupportedContent">
    <ul class="navbar-nav mr-auto">
      <li class="nav-item active">
        <a class="nav-link" href="C:\Users\Anon\Desktop\CVWebsite\cv.html"><span>Home</span> <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" href="C:\Users\Anon\Desktop\CVWebsite\cvAbout.html"><span>About</span></a>
      </li>
      <li> class="nav-item dropdown">
        <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="#" id="navbarDropdown" role="button" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
            <span>Portfolio</span>
        </a>
        <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdown">
          <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Professional</a>
          <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Personal</a>
          <!-- <div class="dropdown-divider"></div> -->
          <!-- <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Something else here</a> -->
         </div>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" href="C:\Users\Anon\Desktop\CVWebsite\cvContact.html"><span class=""><i class="far fa-paper-plane" style="margin-right: 0.5rem;"></i>Contact</span></a>
      </li>
    </ul>
```

```
var par=document.querySelectorAll(".nav-link");
var partext=document.querySelectorAll(".nav-link span");



for (var j=0;j<par.length;j++){
    par[j].addEventListener("mouseenter",function () {
        // this.style.backgroundColor= "red";


        this.classList.toggle("hoverlendin");
    });
    par[j].addEventListener("mouseleave",function () {
        // this.style.backgroundColor= "red";

        this.classList.toggle("hoverlendin");
    });
    partext[j].addEventListener("mouseenter",function () {
        // this.style.backgroundColor= "red";


        this.classList.toggle("navlinktext");
    });
    partext[j].addEventListener("mouseleave",function () {
        // this.style.backgroundColor= "red";

        this.classList.toggle("navlinktext");
    });
```

```py
.navlinktext{

text-decoration-color: white;
  color: white;
  font-size: 1.5rem;

}


.hoverlendin{

  background-color: lightcoral;

}
```

Home, About and Portfolio items change background and text color as expected, however Contact item only changes background, the text remmains the same. What I am doing wrong?

Comment: Why don't use css `:hover`?

Comment: Have you inspected(right-click > inspect) the element to see if there is any css rules overriding it?

Comment: There are no overriding rules and css:hover simply won't work

Comment: This is _most likely_ caused by the nested element `<i>` being clicked upon. When the event bubbles up to the `<a>` element, the keyword `this` does not represent the `<a>`.

Answer (score 0):

**querySelectorAll** count was getting mismatched due to the two spans under **.nav-link** in first element.

Please find the correct version of code below.

```js
var par=document.querySelectorAll(".nav-link");
var partext=document.querySelectorAll(".nav-link span");

for (var j=0;j<par.length;j++){
    par[j].addEventListener("mouseenter",function () {
        // this.style.backgroundColor= "red";


        this.classList.toggle("hoverlendin");
    });
    par[j].addEventListener("mouseleave",function () {
        // this.style.backgroundColor= "red";

        this.classList.toggle("hoverlendin");
    });
    partext[j].addEventListener("mouseenter",function () {
        // this.style.backgroundColor= "red";


        this.classList.toggle("navlinktext");
    });
    partext[j].addEventListener("mouseleave",function () {
        // this.style.backgroundColor= "red";

        this.classList.toggle("navlinktext");
    });
   }
```

```css
.navlinktext {
  text-decoration-color: white;
  color: white;
  font-size: 1.5rem;
}


.hoverlendin {
  background-color: lightcoral;
}
```

```html
<div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarSupportedContent">
    <ul class="navbar-nav mr-auto">
      <li class="nav-item active">
        <a class="nav-link" href="C:\Users\Anon\Desktop\CVWebsite\cv.html"><span class="linkSpan">Home <p class="sr-only" style="display:inline-block;margin:0;">(current)</p></span> </a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" href="C:\Users\Anon\Desktop\CVWebsite\cvAbout.html"><span class="linkSpan">About</span></a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item dropdown">
        <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="#" id="navbarDropdown" role="button" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
            <span class="linkSpan">Portfolio</span>
        </a>
        <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdown">
          <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Professional</a>
          <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Personal</a>
          <!-- <div class="dropdown-divider"></div> -->
          <!-- <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Something else here</a> -->
         </div>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" href="C:\Users\Anon\Desktop\CVWebsite\cvContact.html"><span class="linkSpan"><i class="far fa-paper-plane" style="margin-right: 0.5rem;"></i>Contact</span></a>
      </li>
    </ul>
    </div>
```